# Difference of color code in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

In my JSP i have declared body background as #FFF. For all browsers this supperts except IE browser. In IE Browser it shows black. Why it is happened. But when am giving Color code as #FFFFFF (6 digit ) it works. So which is the standard format. Give some advice on css

Comment: `#FFF` is just a shortcut.
Using longer version is more consistent eg. when you're dealing with custom colors- not as obvious as white.
Proper notation for RGB in HEX consists `6` digits and/or letters.

Comment: Have you added inline styles or through CSS?

Comment: No Suresh. I have use html attribute as bgcolor